# The Treasure of The Mictal Kings

Tags: visual, story

So this is it. The last challenge. Here's where I either get filthy rich, or get myself killed like ol' Professor Alembic.

[image: Trick or treat]

Goodness, I hope that's not *his* skull.

That's the door to the legendary Treasure of the Mictal kings... or to my doom. I have to find out exactly how much to turn the dial. It's just like a safe door, really, only it'll activate a death trap if I guess the wrong number.

Hmmm... Let's take a look at my illustrations from the journey here. Maybe I can find some clue there.

[image: circle]

[image: worship]

[image: writing]

[image: pattern]

Comment: Whoa, I love this

Comment: Very nice presentation! +1 from me for sure!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> turning the dial 59 steps should be right

We will look at the bottom four pictures numbering them from 1 to 4.

First number 3 (the stone):

> The Symbols on the stone are mathematical formulas in unary system. (only counting ones)
>   Each vertical line $|$ is a one and for each single number you simply count the vertical lines.
>   Each two horizontal lines $=$ is an addition symbol.
>   Each square $\square$ is a multiplication symbol.
>   Each T-like symbol $T$ is an equality symbol.
>   Therefore we get the following equations:
>   $$2=2$$
>   $$3=3$$
>   $$1+3=2+2$$
>   $$2\times2=2+2$$
>   $$1\times4=2\times2$$

Next is number 4 (the plate):

> This is a mathematical term.
>
> First we have to calculate the corners with the respective mathematical operators.
>   Corners 1 and 4 (counted left to right, top to bottom) are products of something.
>   Corners 2 and 3 are sums of something.
>
> Next we go one step to the middle.
>   Corners 1 and 2 are added to get the top half.
>   Corners 3 and 4 are multiplied to get the bottom half.
>
> Finally the top and bottom half are added.
>
> We get the following term.
>   $$((1_a\times1_b)+(2_a+2_b))+((3_a+3_b)\times(4_a\times4_b))$$

But where do we get the numbers to put into this term.

> In picture number 1 (the hill) we can see stones that have numbers in the same unary system as in picture 3 written on them.
>   We can also see a pedestal. The same pedestal as on the plate in picture 4.
>   In picture 4 however the pedestal is on the right side of the plate so we have to imagine the stones in picture 1 rotated by 180$^\circ$ as if standing on the other side.
>
> With this we can see the needed corners.
>   Corner 1 is 5 and 6
>   Corner 2 is 7 and 8
>   Corner 3 is 3 and 4
>   Corner 4 is 1 and 2

Lets fill in the term.

$$((5\times6)+(7+8))+((3+4)\times(1\times2))$$
$$=(30+15)+(7\times2)$$
$$=45+14$$
$$=59$$

Therefore I think that the dial has to be turned 59 steps.

As for the symbol in picture 2 I think it is a red herring and has nothing to do with the dial since i was not able to think of anything it could be used for.

Comment: Hmm, what if you have to look at the **board** upside-down, instead of the hilltop. That could be one thing that the second picture is implying, since it shows the sun symbol beneath the curve, while the board shows it above the curve.

Comment: @SpiritFryer I think that the drawing on the board below the symbol is actually the pedestal. In any case it won't make a difference to the solution, if I look at the board upside-down instead of looking at the hilltop upside-down.

Comment: My original plan was to use the sun-symbol to show which way is east; but it turned out to be too hard to make it clear which way east is, so I used the pedestal instead. Somehow, the sun ended up staying.

Comment: @The Dark Truth I realize your answer is accepted so you were right, but let me explain my thoughts. If we assume that the second picture means that the curve on the pedestal has to be downwards, then one has to look at both the hilltop and the board upside-down. However, on the upside-down board the pedestal would be left of the stones. From our current orientation on the upside-down hilltop, the pedestal would be to the right, so for it to be left, we have to look from the other side. From other side, upside-down, the corners would be (left to right, top to bottom):  1-2, 3-4, 5-6, 7-8.

Comment: (Continuation) And consequently, the equation would be (remember, the board is upside-down too, so we're multiplying the two **top** quarters together, not the bottom ones): ((1x2)x(3+4))+((5+6)+(7x8)) = 2x7 + 11+56 = 14 + 67 = 81.